# Problema con intent dentro de clase RecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Estoy probando una app con cardviews y tengo un archivo java llamado RecyclerAdapter.java, pero al incorporarle dentro de un OnClickListener una de sus cards, no me reconoce el codigo

esta es la clase RecyclerAdapter.java:

```
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView itemImage;
        TextView itemTitle;
        TextView itemDetail;

        ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            itemTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            itemDetail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();

                    Snackbar.make(v, "Click detected on chapter " + (position+1),
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }

            });

        }
```

Quiero incorporar dentro de  itemView.setOnClickListener lo siguiente:

```
  if(position==0) {
             Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
             break;
  }
```

Al incorporar el sitch dentro del OnclikListener, el error que me aparece es:

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener, java.lang.Class<com.ebookfrenzy.carddemo.ActivityCanada>)'
```

y en el startActivity me aparece este:

```
Cannot resolve method 'startActivity(android.content.Intent)'
```

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo, realmente era algo simple pero que desconocia, era simplemente pasarle la vista "v" que manejaba tanto en el contexto como en el inicio al paso del activity:

    Intent i1 = new Intent(v.getContext(), ActivityCanada.class);

    v.getContext().startActivity(i1);

Answer (score 0):

```
La solucion es simple, solo es añadirle la vista que el OnClick esta trabajando en este caso es la vista "v" se la paso tanto en el contexto como en el startActivity:

Intent i1 = new Intent(v.getContext(), ActivityCanada.class);
v.getContext().startActivity(i1);
```